# Help with a limit, function to the power of a function

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit:

$$y=\lim_{x\to\infty}
      \left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{x^2\sin(1/x)}$$

From here I do the following:

$$\ln(y)=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})ln(x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x}))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x^2}}\ln(\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}})$$

And from here on I'm stuck with no obvious way to apply L'hopital's rule. Any tips? According to limit calculators $\ln(y)$ should have a value of $-\frac{1}{2}$ and then $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$

Comment: Use `$\sin$` for $\sin$ and use `$\ln$` for $\ln$.

Comment: A hint, yes. Before getting into huge computations, can you see what happens to the base and what happens to the exponent separately? It's less cumbersome, and it shall give you an idea of what to do next. Also, you know that there is probably no point trying the whole thing if you already can't do each part separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$=\frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\ln(x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x}))}{x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-1}x(x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-1)$$ the first two fractions are standard limits, now apply Hopital twice to

$$\frac{x\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-1}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $z = 1/x$,

$$
\begin{split}
L &= \lim_{x\to\infty}(x\ln(1+1/x))^{x^2\sin(1/x)}\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}(\ln(1+z)/z)^{\sin(z)/z^2}\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}((z-z^2/2+O(z^3))/z)^{(z-z^3/6+O(z^5))/z^2}\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}(1-z/2+O(z^2))^{(1-z^2/6+O(z^4))/z}\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\exp(\ln(1-z/2+O(z^2))(1-z^2/6+O(z^4))/z)\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\exp((-z/2+O(z^2))(1-z^2/6+O(z^4))/z)\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\exp((-1/2+O(z))(1-z^2/6+O(z^4)))\\
&=\lim_{z\to 0}\exp(-1/2+O(z))\\
&=e^{-1/2}\\
\end{split}
$$

**Note:**
Wolfy agrees
and says that the expansion is
$$\frac1{\sqrt{e}}\left(1 + \frac{5 z}{24} - \frac{23 z^2}{1152}
                     + \frac{18769 z^3}{414720} - \frac{1526443 z^4}{39813120}
                     + O\left(z^5\right)\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that by Taylor's expansion

$$\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\implies x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=1-\frac1{2x}+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)$$

then

$$\left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{x^2\sin(1/x)}=\left(1-\frac1{2x}+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)^{x^2\sin(1/x)}=\left[\left(1-\frac1{2x}+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)^{\frac1{\frac1{-2x}+o\left(\frac1{x}\right)}}\right]^{\frac{\sin \frac1x}{\frac1x}\left(-\frac1{2}+o\left(1\right)\right)}\to e^{-\frac12}$$

Answer (score 0):

Theorem: Let $c_n \to L$ where $L \ne 0$. Then, then, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n c_n$ exists iff $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$ exists, and the values (if they exist) correspond in the usual way, i.e. $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n c_n = L \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n$

$y=\lim_{x\to\infty}
      \left(x\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)^{x^2\sin(1/x)}$

$= e^{\lim_{x \to \infty}x.\color{blue} {x\sin \dfrac 1x} \ln (x \ln (1+\dfrac1x))}$

$= \exp(\lim_{x\to\infty}x \dfrac{(\ln(x\ln\left(1+\dfrac 1x \right)\color{red}{-1+1})}{\color{blue}{x \ln {(1+\dfrac 1x)-1}}}\color{blue}{(x\ln \left(1+\dfrac 1 x\right)-1)}$

$= \exp (\lim_{x\to\infty}x^2\left(\ln\left(1+\dfrac 1x\right)-\dfrac 1 x\right)$

$= \exp\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\ln{(1+\frac1x)-\frac1x}}{\dfrac 1 {x^2}}\right)$

Now apply L Hopital's rule once,

$= \exp \left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{x^3}{-2(x^3 +x^2)}\right)$

$= \dfrac 1{\sqrt e}$